# How to create more than 1 child process with a loop?

Tags: c, linux, process, parent-child, child-process

How can I create an efficient loop that lets 2 child processes work with 2 different files?

I tried using a loop like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    if((pids[i] = fork()) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Something wrong happened creating child n:%d\n", i+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pids[i] == 0){
        sprintf(nomefile, "file_figlio_%d.txt", i+1);
        fd[i] = open(nomefile, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0660);
        printf("Write on the file n:%d\n", i);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        write(fd[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
        close(fd[i]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

The output is going to be:

```
./7afebb
HELLO 1
Write on the file n:1
HELLO 0
Write on the file n:0
(empty space to fill file 1)
(empty space to fill file 2)
```

How can I make it ask me to fill file 1 and only after that fill file 2?

```
// This is how i corrected the code:

void sig_handler(int sig){
    printf("SIGNAL RECEIVED: %d\n", sig);
    return;
}

for(i = 0; i < n;i++){
        if((pid[i] = fork()) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(pid[i] == 0){
            pause();
            sprintf(nomefile, "figlio_mag%d.txt", i+1);
            fd[i] = open(nomefile, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0660);
            printf("Write on the file:\n");
            fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
            write(fd[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
            close(fd[i]);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
} 
action.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("PARENT: Click enter to write on file n:%d\n", i);
    getchar();
    kill(pid[i], SIGUSR1);
    wait(0);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: both child start and the fgets only works on the first file. EXAMPLE:
Write on the file n:0
Write on the file n:0
(i write something here)
the shell closes the processes right here, and the only file created was the first one

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do yourself and every reader a favor and apply some decent indentation to your code. It is barely readable. Also, you should use parentheses in your conditions: `if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0)` to avoid confusion.

Comment: For debugging, you might print the value of `i` before you open the file.

Comment: i did, now it works but now the output is: -HELLO 1 (line 1)
- Write on the file n: 1
- HELLO 0
- Write on the file n: 0 (line 4)
- (I have to write here on line 5 and 6)
It doesn't stop to hear what to write before creating the second child

Comment: Please edit the question with the additional details of the problem.

Comment: Note that there's no assurance that child 0 will run before child 1, they can run in either order.

Comment: There may be an issue due to duplication of the stdio input buffer when you fork.

Comment: If you want the files written sequentially, there's no point in using multiple processes.  However, one way to enforce sequential execution is to use `else { int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) printf "PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status); }` after the `if (pids[i] == 0)` statement. You also need `#include <sys/wait.h>`.
 Using `fgets(…, stdin)` will work "OK" if the standard input is a terminal, but you'd have to indicate EOF twice.  It won't work if the standard input is a pipe or a file.

Comment: At the end managed to solve my problem using signals.  This way every child process had to wait his own signal to start and make a new file. :)